# How to draw refractions from a lass sphere in ray tracing?

Tags: python, 3d, raytracing

I have a simple ray tracer in python, but I couldn’t make refractions in a sphere using any of the guides.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def normalize(vector):  # normalize vector
    return vector / np.linalg.norm(vector)


def refracted(vector, norm, n1, n2):  # simulates vector refraction
    n = n1 / n2
    cosI = -np.dot(norm, vector)
    sinT2 = n ** 2 * (1 - cosI ** 2)
    cosT = np.sqrt(1 - sinT2)
    return n * vector + (n * cosI - cosT) * norm


def sphere_intersect(center, radius, ray_ray_origin, ray_ray_direction, glass):
    b = 2 * np.dot(ray_ray_direction, ray_ray_origin - center)
    c = np.linalg.norm(ray_ray_origin - center) ** 2 - radius ** 2
    delta = b ** 2 - 4 * c
    if delta > 0:
        t1 = (-b + np.sqrt(delta)) / 2
        t2 = (-b - np.sqrt(delta)) / 2
        if t1 > 0 and t2 > 0 and not glass:
            # returns min distance to intersection
            return min(t1, t2)
        if glass:
            # returns cords of intersection
            return ray_ray_origin + max(t1, t2) * ray_ray_direction
    return None


def nearest_intersected_object(objects, ray_ray_origin, ray_ray_direction, glass=False):
    distances = [sphere_intersect(obj['center'], obj['radius'], ray_ray_origin, ray_ray_direction, glass) for obj in objects]
    nearest_object = None
    min_distance = np.inf
    for index, distance in enumerate(distances):
        if distance and distance < min_distance:
            min_distance = distance
            nearest_object = objects[index]
    return nearest_object, min_distance


width = 300
height = 200
max_depth = 10

camera = np.array([0, 0, 1])
ratio = float(width) / height
screen = (-1, 1 / ratio, 1, -1 / ratio)  # screen cords

light = {'position': np.array([1, 3, 4])}

objects = [
    {'center': np.array([0.0, 0, 0.3]), 'radius': 0.35, 'type': 'glass'},
    {'center': np.array([0, -9000, 0]), 'radius': 9000 - 0.7, 'color': np.array([0.9, 0.9, 0.9]), 'type': 'sphere'},
]

image = np.zeros((height, width, 3))
for i, y in enumerate(np.linspace(screen[1], screen[3], height)):
    for j, x in enumerate(np.linspace(screen[0], screen[2], width)):

        # screen and start vector

        pixel = np.array([x, y, 0])
        ray_origin = camera
        ray_direction = normalize(pixel - ray_origin)

        # intersection
        nearest_object, min_distance = nearest_intersected_object(objects, ray_origin, ray_direction)
        if nearest_object is None:
            continue  # ray_goes_to_infinity

        intersection = ray_origin + min_distance * ray_direction
        normal_to_surface = normalize(intersection - nearest_object['center'])
        shifted_point = intersection + 1e-5 * normal_to_surface
        # if for type 'glass' 
        if nearest_object['type'] == 'glass':
            # 1st refraction
            ray_origin = shifted_point
            ray_direction = refracted(ray_direction, normal_to_surface, 1, 1.5)
            # 2nd refraction
            min_distance = sphere_intersect(nearest_object['center'], nearest_object['radius'], ray_origin, ray_direction, True)
            normal_to_surface = normalize(ray_origin + min_distance * ray_direction - nearest_object['center'])
            intersection = ray_origin + min_distance * ray_direction
            ray_origin = intersection
            ray_direction = refracted(ray_direction, normal_to_surface, 1, 1.5)
            # floor
            nearest_object = objects[1]
            if nearest_object is None:
                continue  # ray_goes_to_infinity

        color = np.zeros(3)
        color += nearest_object['color']
        # chess_floor_to_check_refractions
        if nearest_object['type'] == 'sphere' and (round(intersection[0]) % 2 == 0 and round(intersection[2]) % 2 != 0
                                                or round(intersection[0]) % 2 != 0 and round(
                    intersection[2]) % 2 == 0):
            color = np.zeros(3)
        image[i, j] = np.clip(color, 0, 1)
    print(f'{"%.1f" % (i/height * 100)}% complete')
plt.imsave('shitty_balls.png', image)
```

The problem may be in the refraction function itself, because it behaves very strangely when the angle between the vector and the normal is more than 90 degrees (this appears when the ray leaves the sphere)

[image: Sus behavior]

For now, here's how I'm trying to simulate refractions (# if for type 'glass'):

1. find the distance to the first intersection with the sphere, find the normal to the surface
2. Find the coordinates of this intersection
3. according to the formula from the Internet, I find the direction of the new vector, taking into account refraction
4. I repeat the algorithm for the second refraction and exit of the beam from the sphere

P.S. For now, I'll manage with only two refractions without everything else

P.P.S. I don't know exactly about the refraction function, but there is definitely a problem with my 'if for type glass'. After executing this 'if', 'origin' should be outside of the glass ball, but 'origin' is in it.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I tried my best